# order by in mdx query

Tags: sql-server, mdx, analysis

I want to order by only one element in the column, but code which I already write order by two elements:

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      CrossJoin
      (
        [Data Zameldowania].[Data zameldowania].[Miesiac slownie]
       ,[Data Zameldowania].[Rok].[Rok]
      )
    } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {[Pokoj].[Typ].[Typ]} ON 1
FROM [Hurtownia Danych]
WHERE 
  [Measures].[Rezerwacja Count];
```

Here is the output of my query:

[image]

Here is what I try to do, but it doesn't work:

```
  NON EMPTY 
    Order
    (
      {
        CrossJoin
        (
          [Data Zameldowania].[Data zameldowania].[Miesiac slownie]
         ,[Data Zameldowania].[Rok].[Rok]
        )
      }
     ,desc
    ) ON 0
```

Is possible to order by only on "[Miesiac slownie]"? If so what I could do to achieve this? I will be very grateful for help!

Comment: Sory I don't see any order by Clause

Comment: @ericpap in my query there isn't order by, but I add a part of query with order by under the output picture.

Comment: So if you add at the end of your query: "ORDER BY [Miesiac slownie]", does it work?

Comment: Nope it doesn't. I get following error: Analyzer: cannot recognize instruction dialect, because of ambigous.

Comment: Does the column "[Miesiac slownie]" exist on [Hurtownia Danych] table?

Comment: Yes, it exist in [Hurtownia Danych] table

Comment: Sorry having some trouble to understand what you are trying to do whith you query especially with tables and field name beeing so complicated. Why aren't you using joins?

Comment: Because crossjoin works fine for me, only the ordering doesn't :c

Comment: @ericpap This query is MDX, not SQL

Comment: Oh yes i see that. Sorry my mistake

Comment: @Tadek The [MDX order function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145587.aspx) requires the set you want to order as well as a numeric or string expression by which to order it.  Then you can also specify the order { ASC | DESC | BASC | BDESC } as an optional parameter. It looks like you are missing the numeric or string expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Add this in front of your query:

```
WITH MEMBER [MEASURES].[X] AS
    [Data Zameldowania].[Data zameldowania].[Miesiac slownie].membervalue
```

Then amend your order snippet to this:

```
NON EMPTY 
Order
(
    [Data Zameldowania].[Data zameldowania].[Miesiac slownie] *
    [Data Zameldowania].[Rok].[Rok],
 [MEASURES].[X]
 ,bdesc  //<< changed to break natural hier order
) ON 0
```

---

Second attempt. Please try using the member name property. So try the following

Add this in front of your query:

```
WITH MEMBER [MEASURES].[X] AS
    [Data Zameldowania].[Data zameldowania].[Miesiac slownie].CurrentMember.PROPERTIES("Name")
```

Then amend your order snippet to this:

```
NON EMPTY 
Order
(
    [Data Zameldowania].[Data zameldowania].[Miesiac slownie] *
    [Data Zameldowania].[Rok].[Rok],
 [MEASURES].[X]
 ,bdesc  //<< changed to break natural hier order
) ON 0
```

Comment: Still the same result column [Miesiac slownie] isn't in right order.

Comment: is `[Miesiac slownie]` a member ? or a hierarchy?

Comment: ok - I've added a second attempt which should order alphabetically by the name of the member of `[Miesiac slownie]`

Comment: Yes miesiac slownie is a hierarchy. And my hierarchy looks like: [Data Zameldowania].[Data zameldowania].[Rok] or [Miesiac slownie] or [dzien slownie]

Comment: I edit a little bit Yours proposition and it works perfectly for me!

I change member to [Data Zameldowania].[Data zameldowania].CurrentMember.Name and also in order change bdesc to basc

. Also I have a question is there a better option to show info from hierarchy? I want to show info  of 2 elements from 3 (from hierarchy [Data Zameldowania].[Data zameldowania], so this is why I use crossjoin?